# Error : IBM WAS cannot retrieve the key 'vivek' from "D:\policyset\client.jks" keystore

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, saml, ws-security

I'm using IBM Websphere server **policy & binding** for securing my web service application by taking the guide of Red book "Was v7 : Web Service guide" but after going through all the steps While I tried to access the web service using the web client which is also using policy and binding as per the guide given in the book. But still I m getting a error saying.....

> > Error 500: javax.xml.ws.soap.SoapFaultException: com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.SoapSecurityException: CWWSS6521E: The login failed because of an exception: javax.security.auth.login.loginException: com.ibm.wsspi.wssecurity.core.SoapSecurityException: CWWSS5312E: The application server cannot retrieve 'vivek' key from the **"D:\policyset\sender.jks" keystore. The following Exception occurred : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Password cannot be null.

**Note :**

**1. keystore** files are **generated by myself** using a ibm's ikeyman.bat file available as part of websphere server.

**2. vivek key** which server say's cannot find is the alias name of keystore.

**3. I using sun jdk** to generate this keystore as the same command is not working with ibm's was jdk.

**4. In web service** I'm just sending a text to server and returning it back to client. I'm not performing any sort of authentication except ibm's policy.

**5. Here also I an encrypting** only soap request body nothing else in request or response.

Please help me and let me know if any other details required.

Sorry guys I cannot upload screen sort as The issue is on development computer where I don't have access to public internet as well we have no way to transfer any file from development machine to this VM.

**Please suggest reference** if you have already gone through that and it's working for you or some one to whom you have refer or got reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the above problem is we need to export the public/client certificate from server's jks(Java key store) and then we have to import the same certificate in client's jks.

> > *Command* : ***keytool -export/-import -keystore examplestore.jks -alias aliasName -file fileName.cer***

**Reference**: *http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step5.html*

This solves my problem.

Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all: password cannot be null, so you're not providing the password that java can use to look up the certificate in your keystore.

Comment: Yes, I have provided the password for the keystore while configuring the binding for the web service in the websphere admin console.

Answer (score 0):

The password cannot be null might be a generic error. I would say there might be some compatibility issue while creating this key store using a SUN JDK and then trying to use an IBM SDK environment. Even though they're both essentially Java, the IBM SDK uses it's own proprietary JCE provider.

One test you can try is to attempt to open this key store using one of the IBM tools like iKeyman which you can find under /AppServer/java/jre/bin/ if you fail opening the keystore even by supplying the right password then that's the problem you need to rectify. You would need to use an IBM tool to create the keystore.

Comment: Later I used ikeyman.bat tools as well to create key store file and  checked as well to open it every thing is working fine. I'm able to view the aliases as well created by me. But still it's giving the same error.